# How to import projects to Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle

Hi I download some project from GitHub, but when I import them , I receive error(downloading gradle).
Project gradle is 2.2.0 , I download it and place in ".gradle/wrraper/dists" and I ticked offline gradle but I receive error again.

Comment: Simply Go to File -->open --> select the project you want to import--> finish

Answer (score 1):

Click on `File` -> `New` -> `Project from Version Control` -> `Github`

[image]

do this

[image],

The error does not belong to the `Android Studio` or `Github` but there is `gradle` conflict of the version.

You would have to updated the `Gradle` version depending on version you have.

Update:
download [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) from here, You may also choose plugins

[image]

Comment: I receive this error:[link](http://www.uplooder.net/img/image/56/6ffde5564b410707a6282ad4bff84518/Screenshot-(19).png)

Comment: @Mr.Mr it means you don't have git installed on your computer or it is not configured properly, you would have to install in separately or get the git plugin though Android Studio

Comment: @Mr.Mr, kindly send me the link of the project which is on github i will check whats going on

Comment: I do it but gradle error again,errors for libraries.

Comment: depending on what version of Android Studio you have it will prompt you to update the **gradle** version accordingly, I would suggest you to update your android studio. Currently the **gradle** was updated by my android studio to **com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2**

Comment: my android studio is version 2.1.2, I live in Iran,maybe is unavailable in Iran,so can I download it from internet and copy to .gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Simply Go to File -->open --> select the project you want to import--> finish

Comment: That is commented by me :)

Comment: yeah i know. but you remove from anyone

Answer (score 0):

Try import your project in android studio. Using project level build.gradle.

Like File --> Import Project --> (Open your project build.gradle file)

Answer (score 0):

First Open android studio -->Select File menu -->click on open -->pop new windows-->select project -->click ok -->finish